# getting client computer name in a flex web application?

Tags: .net, apache-flex, computer-name

is it possible to obtain the computer name of the client using flex?

I made a small intranet application and I need to log computer access to it.

I used Flex 3.4 and web services in .net 3.5

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in a browser based app.  The Security Sandbox that the browser places the Flash Player in prevents it from getting such information from the machine it is running on.

In an AIR App you may be able to do something using [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process.html).